# How to read from dynamodb using apigateway VTL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I want to read dynamodb records using API gateway VTL mapping template directly. I am using HTTP post method to read and integration method POST as well.

Lets say I have a table with 3 attributes and Id is primary, name and address are other attributes.

I want to read all the records based on name attribute.
What would be the VTL and partiql query for that?